# Chrome onmousemove frequency strangely depends on devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseevent, mousemove

I've found a really weird issue. I'm making a drawing app with line smoothness. It works perfectly with devtools on. But I've noticed that mousemove event is fired less frequently when the devtools window is closed. How could it even happen?!

[with devtools on and without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpSlD.png)

Answer (score 1):

When the developer tools are closed, multiple pointer move events are "coalesced" into one event, which then gets fired less frequently. You can get all the individual events by calling `event.getCoalescedEvents()`. See more information here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/getCoalescedEvents